# Makefile, Loading External Source

Tags: makefile

Whatever, I don't really care about the privacy anymore. If it does work, what is the point of keeping it? I will change the file names a little however. This is the original code.

```
CXX=g++
CXXFLAGS= -Wall
LDFLAGS=-Wno-deprecated -fPIC -pthread
DIR=Exedir/

EXOoffline=EXOdir/offline/
EXOofflinelib=utilities/misc utilities/database utilities/calib reconstruction analysis/manager analysis/jni analysis/root geant/EXOsim
LIBRARY=-lGui -L/usr/lib/root/5.09 -lMinuit -L/nfs/rabbitybunny/g/exo-software/software/hudson/builds-rhel5/build-id/1077/lib -lEXOUtilities -lEXOSim -lEXOROOT -lEXODBUtilities -lEXOAnalysisManager -lEXOAnalysisJNI -lEXOCalibUtilities -lEXOReconstruction -L/afs/rabbitybunny.edu/package/cernroot/vol35/52800svn/Linux26SL5_i386_gcc412/lib -lTreePlayer
INCLUDE=-I $(ROOTSYS)/include `root-config --glibs` -I /nfs/rabbitybunny/g/exo/software/builds/current/include
INCLUDE+=$(addprefix -I$(EXOoffline),$(EXOofflinelib))

all: run

run: main.o
        $(CXX) main.o -o $(DIR)$@ $(LIBRARY)
.cpp.o:
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) -c -o $@ $<

#run: main.cpp
#       $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) $(LIBRARY) main.cpp -o $(DIR)$@

.PHONY: clean
clean:
        rm -rf *.o $(DIR)run
```

and I get this.

```
rabbitybunny@enigma $ make clean
rm -rf *.o Exedir/run
rabbitybunny@enigma $ make
g++ -Wall -I /afs/rabbitybunny.edu/package/cernroot/vol35/52800svn/Linux26SL5_i386_gcc412/include `root-config --glibs` -I /nfs/rabbitybunny/g/exo/software/builds/current/include -IEXOdir/offline/utilities/misc -IEXOdir/offline/utilities/database -IEXOdir/offline/utilities/calib -IEXOdir/offline/reconstruction -IEXOdir/offline/analysis/manager -IEXOdir/offline/analysis/jni -IEXOdir/offline/analysis/root -IEXOdir/offline/geant/EXOsim -c -o main.o main.cpp
g++: -lCore: linker input file unused because linking not done
g++: -lCint: linker input file unused because linking not done
g++: -lRIO: linker input file unused because linking not done
g++: -lNet: linker input file unused because linking not done
g++: -lHist: linker input file unused because linking not done
g++: -lGraf: linker input file unused because linking not done
g++: -lGraf3d: linker input file unused because linking not done
g++: -lGpad: linker input file unused because linking not done
g++: -lTree: linker input file unused because linking not done
g++: -lRint: linker input file unused because linking not done
g++: -lPostscript: linker input file unused because linking not done
g++: -lMatrix: linker input file unused because linking not done
g++: -lPhysics: linker input file unused because linking not done
g++: -lMathCore: linker input file unused because linking not done
g++: -lThread: linker input file unused because linking not done
g++: -lGui: linker input file unused because linking not done
g++: -lm: linker input file unused because linking not done
g++: -ldl: linker input file unused because linking not done
g++ main.o -o Exedir/run -lGui -L/usr/lib/root/5.09 -lMinuit -L/nfs/rabbitybunny/g/exo-software/software/hudson/builds-rhel5/build-id/1077/lib -lEXOUtilities -lEXOSim -lEXOROOT -lEXODBUtilities -lEXOAnalysisManager -lEXOAnalysisJNI -lEXOCalibUtilities -lEXOReconstruction -L/afs/rabbitybunny.edu/package/cernroot/vol35/52800svn/Linux26SL5_i386_gcc412/lib -lTreePlayer
```

Thanks for helping, I would really appreciate so.
(Maybe I should learn to use cmake instead.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem comes from the `root-config` command in the `INCLUDE` macro:

```
INCLUDE=-I $(ROOTSYS)/include `root-config --glibs` ...
```

If you run that, it will probably list a whole bunch of `-lXxx` options — the ones the compiler is saying are unused because you aren't linking when you create an object file.

Run `root-config --glibs` and look at the output.  Then find a different option to generate the include options instead of the libraries.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was exactly the problem. "root-config" belongs to the LIBRARY. Never thought that would be the problem. However, when I type in main.o in shell though, it gives ### main.o: Exec format error. Wrong Architecture.### Is that normal?

Comment: An object file (`.o`) cannot be run: it's not a program.  It's a bit of a program, that's compiled into a format that makes it easy to link into a program.  So you would _never_ try to run a `.o` file and the error you're seeing is not abnormal.  Also, about `root-config` : if you give it the `--glibs` option it will print out the libraries to link.  If you give it other options it will print out other things, such as the include directories etc.

Comment: Oh, yeah, just realize we can do root-config --incdir too. And thank you for the not about .o files. Oh, by the way, if you wish to post the solution on the other page, I can give you credit (better than leaving it unsolved). Cheers.

Comment: @MadScientist: see Rabbitybunny's comment above and either contribute to the 'close as duplicate' or add an answer to [Makefile loading outside source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17801137/makefile-loading-outside-source).

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any idea why you're creating a brand new question that essentially duplicates your existing question, except the examples are tidier.  Why not just edit your existing question?

Anyway, the problem is that the rule `.cpp.o` is *compiling* the code (turning the source file `.cpp` into an object file `.o`), but you're passing *linker* flags to it (`-L$(LIBDIR)` etc.)  Similarly, when you *link* the code with the `run` target, you *don't* pass linker flags to it.

Also generally you do *NOT* want to put the `-c` flag in the `CXXFLAGS` variable, because generally you want to use that variable on both the compile and link lines to be sure that your flags are consistent.

Rewrite:

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -wall
CPPFLAGS = -I$(INCDIR)

all: run
run: run.o
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) run.o -o $@ -L$(LIBDIR) -lpng
.cpp.o:
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

Comment: Does the order matter though? Except for -o. Well, id doesn't seem to work by removing include from run though.

Comment: Oh, and I repeated the question for many reasons. You can summarize it as the Chinese way of doing things. (Maybe that is against the policy here, I will pay attention next time).

Comment: Does what order matter?  Some order does matter, and some doesn't.  For example, the order of the `-I` and `-L` flags matters because that's the order in which the compiler will search directories for headers or libraries.  The order of `-l` matters because that's the order the linker will link in libraries, and often libraries need to be linked in a particular order.  The order of `-o` vs. `-c` doesn't matter (but remember `$@` goes with `-o`).  You can read the documentation for your compiler: it will explain all the flags and explain which ones need to be ordered and which don't.

Comment: And thank you too MadScientist, especially on being so patient in answering my questions.